# Capturing output and counting its lines

Tags: bash, find, wc

I'd like to run a `find` command and then count the lines of the output as well as give out the output of the result.  My straight-forward approach was this:

```
output=$(find ...)
lines=$(echo "$output" | wc -l)
echo "$output"
```

But unfortunately using `echo` to pipe this into `wc` adds a newline, so even if the `find` did not find anything (zero lines of output), that `wc` is giving out `1` (for the newline which the `echo` appended.

I changed the `echo` to a `printf` to prevent appending the newline to the output but then also a one-line output of `find` like `var/` was without a newline, and hence the `wc` gave out `0`.

The problem is in the capturing of the output (`$(...)`).  It strips trailing newlines which in my case are relevant.

Can this be prevented somehow?

Is there a completely different approach on my original task?

Comment: Related: [How to avoid bash command substitution to remove the newline character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184358/how-to-avoid-bash-command-substitution-to-remove-the-newline-character)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm now using a workaround by appending a fake line to the output; this way I can rely on the fact that one line will always be present, and this way the empty line is easily distinguishable from the one-line:

```
r=$(find var/ -name var -printf "%p\n"; echo '==')
# appending additional line to be able to distinguish 0 from 1 found file
case "$(echo "$r" | wc -l)" in
  1)  # means 0 found files
    ...
  2)  # means 1 found file
    ...
  *)  # means more found files
    ...
esac
```

Comment: And what about your actual output?

Comment: I guess you want to know how I can live with the additional `==` below the output.  Actually, I can live with that, yes ;-)  And in the case where it does not suit me fine, I strip that off.

Answer (score 5):

A simple workaround that would occur to mind would be to check if the string is empty:

```
[ -z "$output" ] && count=0 || count=$(wc -l <<< "$output")
```

Now `count` would be `0` if `find` didn't produce any output else it would contain the number of lines in the output.

Answer (score 3):

**Counting new lines after storing find's output in a variable is always going to be problematic in case your file names contain spaces or new lines.**

I would suggest using find like this (to count all `*.txt` files and print them)

```
output=
c=0

while read -d ''; do 
    ((c++))
    output+="$REPLY"$'\n'
done < <(find . -name "*.txt" -print0)

echo "c=$c"
echo "output=$output"
```

**PS:** This will also take care of new lines/spaces in file names.

Comment: Nice solution for the hard-ass case (when I have no idea what kind of input I'm expecting).  In my case I know pretty much what the output will look like.  There will be no spaces or newlines in the file names, that's sth I can rely on.  So I'd rather not complicate my code with a solution like yours.  But reading the output line by line to count it sounds like a good idea.  I'll consider that.