# How to do a try catch in bash scripts with curly braces?

Tags: bash

A recommended pattern that mimics try-catch in bash scripts is to use curly braces. This does not work as expected, though. The following script outputs `A B 1`. Why is that the case and how must the script be modified to output the intended `A C 1`?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

{
  echo "A"
  false
  echo "B"
} || echo "C"

{
  echo "1"
  false
  echo "2"
}
```

Comment: see also [Is there a TRY CATCH command in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009364/is-there-a-try-catch-command-in-bash). short: use subshells to catch `exit 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many issues with the 'set -e' - it does not work well in many error conditions. This has been covered in many posting, just search 'errexit bash'. For example: [Bash subshell errexit semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29532904/bash-subshell-errexit-semantics)

At this time, there is no clean solution. However, there are good news. I'm working on a proposed change that will allow the above to work. See discussion in bash-bug archive: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2022-07/index.html
And proposal: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2022-07/msg00006.html

**Final proposal for the 'errfail' can be found: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2022-07/msg00055.html**

I expect to have the solution submitted for review by the bash dev team this week. Hopefully it will get accepted into next bash release.

It will support new 'errfail' option

```
set -o errfail
{ echo BEFORE ; false ; echo AFTER ; } || echo "CATCH"
```

and will output: BEFORE CATCH

If you are looking for more fancy solution consider:

```
alias try=''
alias catch='||'
try {
    echo BEFORE
    false
    echo AFTER
} catch { echo CATCH ; }
```

Comment: Great answer! Could you please explain, how the alias solution works? Does it prevent bash from applying the "boolean" logic that disables errexit for the subshell?

Comment: Yes, exactly as you said.  It also avoid the "boolean" logic associated with '||', '&&', and other related glitches. See reference to latest post (which does include a patch against latest development branch). If you like this approach, consider joining the bash-bug group and providing your view. I believe community support will help.

Comment: Note that the alias is simply a fancier option to mimic Python, etc. The actual logic is built into the various bash flow control statements: if, while, for, etc.

Answer (score 1):

A *work-around* using 2 separate bash invokations:

```bash
bash -c 'set -e; echo "A"; false; echo "B"' || echo 'C'

bash -c 'set -e; echo "1"; false; echo "2"'
```

Or with intendations:

```bash
bash -c '
   set -e
   echo "A"
   false
   echo "B"
' || echo 'C'

bash -c '
   set -e
   echo "1"
   false
   echo "2"
'
```

**Output:**

```bash
A
C
1
```

[**Code Demo**](https://ideone.com/H0bh5u)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `&&` and remove this dangerous hardly predictable `set -e`.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

{
  echo "A" &&
  false &&
  echo "B"
} || echo "C"

{
  echo "1" &&
  false &&
  echo "2"
}
```

[Test run it](https://ideone.com/4fhDiT)

There is never anything wrong with being absolutely explicit in code.
Don't count on the implementation to handle even part of the logic.

This is what `set -e` is doing. Handles some logic for you, and it does it very differently from what you'd expect it to be most of the time.

So be **always explicit** and handle error conditions explicitly.