# Is there a program that functions like printf with an entire file as input?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, printf

My use case is as follows.

file.txt

> First arg: %s
> Second %s arg,
> Third %s

Run `prog file.txt "one" "$(ls dir1/dir2)" "three"`

Resulting in

> First arg: one
> Second file1 file2 file3 arg,
> Third three

I first thought to use sed but that inevitably runs into problems when bash substitutions get read as format characters like this `sed s/%1/$VAR/g` -> `sed s/%1/dir1/dir2/file1/g`

I'm thinking I could iterate by lines and take the text before and after a substitute and just insert like

```
FIRST=$(sed "s/%s.*//" <<< $LINE)
SECND=$(sed "s/.*%s//" <<< $LINE)

echo "$FIRST $SUB $SECND"
```

Though that's limited to one sub per line and I would prefer a cleaner solution if it exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `printf` with the whole file as the formatting string:

```sh
printf "$(< file.txt)\n" one two three
```

Notice that command substitution removes trailing newlines, so a separate `\n` is added back; see [How to avoid bash command substitution to remove the newline character?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15184358/3266847) for details.

Comment: Didn't know you could redirect files in this way. Very helpful.

Comment: @M_ Strictly speaking, the `$(< file.txt)`, which is equivalent to `$(cat file.txt)` (but faster), is not redirection. It is command substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following as `prog`:

```
#!/bin/bash

c=1                                     # counter for argv
nl=$'\n'                                # newline character
while IFS= read -r format; do           # read "file.txt" line by line
    (( c++ ))                           # increment the argv counter
    argv="${!c}"                        # obtain the argv indexed by "c"
    printf "${format}\n" "${argv//$nl/ }"
                                        # print the argv formatted by the line of "file.txt"
done < "$1"                             # "$1" is assigned to "file.txt"
```

The substitution `"${argv//$nl/ }"` just converts the newline characters included in the output of `ls` into whitespace characters.